# How to adjust Autolayout positions of resizing UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have the following setup where the `UICollectionView` positioned in between the two headers resizes to fit all its cells. It basically is a 2x2 layout in table format.

[image]

Now once the data is loaded I use the following to resize the `UICollectionView`.

```
- (void)loadContent {

[self.collectionViewAboutProperty reloadData];

[self.labelAddress setText:stringAddress];

float totRows = [self.dictAboutProperty count];

float cHeight = ceil(totRows/2.0);

float collectionHeight = (cHeight * 20) + (cHeight * 5);

[self.collectionViewAboutProperty setFrame:CGRectMake(self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.origin.x, self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.origin.y, self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.size.width, collectionHeight)];

}
```

The problem is that when the above happens it overlaps the bottom header. It is almost as if the Autolayout constraints on the bottom header are completely ignored. At the minute I have it set to a space of about 25pixels from the above `UICollectionView`

How can I make it so that when the content is loaded and the collection view is dymically resized the views below update themselves to meet the constraints?

Thanks

Comment: creating a custom layout is a much better idea, but if you try to put your entire snippet into the `–layoutSubviews` method of your custom subset of `UICollectionView`, that might be a reasonable lightweight solution for you as well – but I would go for the custom layout, more elegant and it is designed for handling such scenarios exactly.

Comment: [self.labelAddress setText:stringAddress];

float totRows = [self.dictAboutProperty count];

float cHeight = ceil(totRows/2.0);

float collectionHeight = (cHeight * 20) + (cHeight * 5);

[self.collectionViewAboutProperty setFrame:CGRectMake(self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.origin.x, self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.origin.y, self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.size.width, collectionHeight)];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.labelAddress setText:stringAddress];

float totRows = [self.dictAboutProperty count];

    float cHeight = ceil(totRows/2.0);

    float collectionHeight = (cHeight * 20) + (cHeight * 5);

    [self.collectionViewAboutProperty setFrame:CGRectMake(self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.origin.x, self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.origin.y, self.collectionViewAboutProperty.frame.size.width, collectionHeight)];
    [self.collectionViewAboutProperty reloadData];
```

will solve your issue.